# A python script to plot a joint probability mass function table

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Consider this example

> Suppose that 3 balls are randomly selected from an urn containing 3
>   red, 4 white, and 5 blue balls. If we let X and Y denote,
>   respectively, the number of red and white balls chosen, then the joint
>   probability mass function of \$X\$ and \$Y\$, \$p(i,j) = P\{X=i,Y=j\}\$, is given by

[image]

This code is to plot such a joint probability mass function table.

```
arr = np.empty((4,4), dtype='U30')
sample_space = []
red_balls = 3
white_balls = 4
blue_balls = 5
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        r = comb(red_balls, i)
        w = comb(white_balls, j)
        b = comb(blue_balls, 3-i-j)
        result = int(r*w*b)
        arr[i][j] = r'$\dfrac{{{}}}{{{}}}$'.format(result, 220)
        sample_space.append(result)
pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

And I got.

[image]

## question

if I want to compute the marginal probability I have to add another empty array which is inefficient, is there a better way to do that?

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: In my opinion, hard-coding `220` is cheating.

Comment: What is `comb` in the code? Where does it come from?

Comment: As Georgy stated, please include the full code you have, this'll help provide a good review.

Comment: Since you've hardcoded the `220`, this is expected. You didn't finish the assignment, you tried to hack your way around it. This code isn't finished.